# What's the point of writing (void*) in front of integer pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, void-pointers, format-specifiers

I read the following program code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


int main () {
    int *p;
    p= malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *p=42; 

    printf("Pointer p has address %p and points to %p\n",
    (void*)&p, (void*)p);

   free(p);    

}
```

My question refers to the following part:

```
printf("Pointer p has address %p and points to %p\n", (void*)&p, (void*)p);
```

I don't understand what the `(void*)` is doing. Is this a cast? What's the point of doing this?

What is the difference of the above to simply writing the following?

```
 printf("Pointer p has address %p and points to %p\n", &p, p);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because, `%p` *explicitly* expects an argument of type `void *`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*

> `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. [....]

Since `printf()` is a variadic function and there is no default argument promotion for pointers, the cast is required.

Strictly speaking, as per the standard mandate, from same chapter, paragraph 7

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

That said, to make the answer complete,

- `p = malloc(sizeof(int));` can be rewritten as `p= malloc(sizeof*p);` to make it more robust.
- You should always check against the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: @Sourav Ghoush: Thank you for your answer. However, the program also works without the (void*) cast. So, it does not seem to be necessary for %p to be supplied a void pointer (instead of, say, an int pointer)

Comment: Sometimes you get "lucky" and UB does what you expect.

Comment: @steady_progress: without the cast, the behavior is *undefined*, since the type of the argument doesn't match what the conversion specifier expects - it may work, it may not.  If `sizeof (int *) != sizeof (void *)`, then you'll probably get garbled output.

Comment: @steady_progress Technically speaking, the cast is required, as mandated in the standard. Without that, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: and undefined behavior includes working right up to the moment when it doesnt (usually in production, at midnight)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what the (void*) is doing. Is this a cast? What's the point of doing this?

Yes, it's a cast. It doesn't seem to be necessary with my compiler (llvm), which gives the following output even if I remove the casts:

```
Pointer p has address 0x7fff501357d8 and points to 0x7fcb38c00390
```

Other compilers may not be so forgiving.